# NullPointerException on running Hibernate Code Generation (HibernateTools)

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-tools

I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: <no message>` on running Hibernate Code Generation from JBoss Tools plugin in eclipse. The stackTrace  seen is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:97)
at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:93)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1816)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you say which versions you are using? It might be this https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-5461?_sscc=t

Comment: I am using JBoss Tools 4.2.3 in eclipse Luna